# InvocationTargetException on inflating an xml - android

Tags: xml, android, inflate

I have a code that works 99% of the time since is deploy in lots of clients, but sometimes I get the following:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:92)
>       java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>       java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
>       android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
>       com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>       android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
>       android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
>       android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
>       android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>       com.mycode.mycode.MyClass.draw(xxxxxxx)
>   .....

and on my code I have:

> LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this
>                       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>               theview = li.inflate(R.layout.partofthescreen,
>                       somecontainer, false);

so the question is why I am getting InvocationTargetException.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try `getLayoutInflater()` instead of your `getSystemService()` call, though I am not sure that will make a difference.

An `InvocationTargetException` comes from reflection, and means the `Method` that was invoked threw an `Exception`. Do you see any sign of another stack trace that might be the underlying `Exception`? If not, try catching `InvocationTargetException` and looking at `getCause()` to see what is really going on.

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem.

I solved that problem by:

Make the local variable

```
private Context **context**;
```

Then in your class constructor( which has argument Context context)  do this

```
this.context=**context**;

LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) **context** .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

theview = li.inflate(R.layout.partofthescreen, somecontainer, false);
```

Comment: It's because `getContext()` might result in a different (wrapped) context than the one passed in the constructor